# What do the variables for tolerance measure in scipy.optimize.minimize?

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

My understanding is that in the method call to `minimize`, `tol` represents the minimum difference in the cost function (i.e the difference in whatever value `fun`, which is the first parameter in the method call, returns) needed for optimization to complete.

```
scipy.optimize.minimize(fun, x0, args=(),
 method=None, jac=None, hess=None, hessp=None, bounds=None, constraints=(),
 tol=None, callback=None, options=None)
```

I'm obviously wrong, however, because when I set `tol = 1E-3`, and print out values of `fun` with each iteration, I see this:

```
0.3078
0.3074
...
```

What does `tol` represent?

Particular optimization algorithms also have another parameter called `xtol`, which is

> xtol : float
>   Average relative error in solution xopt acceptable for convergence.

For example, see:

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.minimize-newtoncg.html#minimize-method-newton-cg

---

So what do `xtol` and `tol` represent, and what are there differences?

Comment: "when I ... print out values of `fun` with each iteration" - are you sure the values you're printing are all actual guesses the function is making? Most optimization algorithms perform more function evaluations than that.

Comment: I'm certain that the values printed are all outputs of `fun`. What additional evaluations do you refer to?

Comment: They're all outputs of `fun`, but not all calls to `fun` are used as solution candidates. `fun` is also called to compute stuff like gradients and trust regions, depending on the optimization method.

Comment: oh. I see. What motivated me to post this question was the fact convergence was taking too long in my implementation. I thought that by reducing tolerance, I could speed it up.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty late to this, but dropping an answer hoping it helps someone later.

There are several Tolerances that can be defined (controlled) during any optimization call. Tol, ftol, xtol, catol and several others.
Largely, you could infer the following from these variables:

*ftol* = Objective function tolerance. Checks to ensure the precision of your maximization/minimization task.

*xtol* = Tolerance of each step. For few algorithms, the step size is a function of trust-region, derivative or simply where the search space is wrt the initial guess. This means you might see variable step size, ideally going from large to small. xtol provides a precision control on when should the solver terminate based on how small steps have become.

*catol* = Constraint Tolerance. Provides a general bound for constraints (if any) in the optimization task.

*gtol* = If the solver/method uses Gradients, this is for controlling that.

Each has there importance based on the problem you are solving and the objectives/constraints involved.